# How do I pass any array to a window being opened with window.open()

Tags: javascript, arrays, window.open

I have any array called `query[]`

I am opening a new window with:

```
  window.open("http://localhost:8081/myapp/Query.action","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=600,height=400");
```

How do I pass this array to the new window so I can use it there.

EDIT: I just found this, [Pass array to Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487420/pass-array-to-window) which will probably provide the answer.

EDIT2: the answer provided in question 2487420 doesn't seem to work, I am using FireFox and openDialog never opens a new window

New Requirement: This only has to work on FireFox because I am only using it for testing.

Comment: what does the array contain? If it's simple items (e.g. numbers) see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "pass" the array, but you can make it available as a global (or via a global), and your new page can use something like:

```
 var theArray = window.opener.theArray;
```

to get access to it.

Alternatively, you *could* pass the array through as a list of parameters, but if it's not otherwise interesting to the server then that would be a little wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass it on the URL as well, for example:

```
window.open("http://localhost:8081/myapp/Query.action?arr=" + query.join(","), "mywindow", ...
```

This will pass it as comma separated list that can be read in the target page.

Comment: Note that the items in the array has to be convertible to string, and they can't contain any characters that are harmful or have a special meaning in the URL, like spaces, colons or slashes, and of course no commas as that would separate one item into two.

Comment: @Guffa thanks, good point. It's possible to use `encodeURIComponent` as well, but first let's see what the OP says.

Comment: I like this option because this way you can access the values in PHP as well.