# Passing variable value in window.open issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have list of values, i want to pass all selected values in window.open, i am able to pass only one variable value to window.open, but i want to pass multiple values as parameter, below is the code how i am passing one value.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" name="select1" id="sbone" size="20">
  <option value="1"> orange </option>
  <option value="2"> apple </option>
  <option value="3"> bnana </option>
</select>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
      val = document.getElementById('sbone').value;
      window.open(+val + "/report1", "mywindow1");
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="button" id="mybutton" name="mybutton" value="click" />
```

Comment: `+ val + "/report1"` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @JackBashford That's not the case, it's valid. The first `+val` is effectively calling `Number(val)`.

Comment: How are you expecting the multiple values to be added to the URL? What should that URL look like?

Comment: for example if i select first two values, url should look like this;
1/report1 \\right now only this one is opening
2/report1

Comment: But you're still only sending the value `1` when `1` and `2` are selected, so how is that going to work?

Comment: i want to know how to pass array of values

Comment: In that case how is your routing configured on the server side? It seems setup for only single values right now, so the easiest way would be to add them to the querystring. In broad terms, the JS is the easy part. The other half of the problem is amending your server side logic to receive this array

Comment: for example if i add this in script, alert($('#sbone').val()); 
it will show all selected values. but how to pass same thing to open different windows with selected values.

Comment: i am using php laravel, if i add hard coded values it is opening just fine, but i want to open selected values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass any array to a window being opened with window.open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848333/how-do-i-pass-any-array-to-a-window-being-opened-with-window-open)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava my question is different

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan solution: <script>

  $(function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
      $("#sbtwo > option").each(function() {
      window.open (+this.value+"/report1", 'name_'+(new Date()).getTime(),"location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=1500,height=900");
  });
  });  });

  </script>

Comment: So you wanted one window per value? That's not what your question or any of the comments mentioned. Please be accurate when asking question in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script which solved my issue:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
$("#sbtwo > option").each(function() {
window.open (+this.value+"/report1", 'name_'+(new Date()).getTime(),"location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=1500,height=900");
}); });  });            
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
var $val = $('#cars').val();

window.open(
  'http://www.goole.com/'+$val,
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <select id="cars">
        <option value="lexus">lexus</option>
        <option value="bugatti">bugatti</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id='mybutton' value="button">
</p>
```

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
window.location = $('#sbone').val();});
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Better add the extra details in the body of the answer itself.

Comment: @Valentino, I have updated my answer please review. Hope it will help.